# Ng-select Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am trying to bind my typescript model to data from the backend to display in an ng-select dropdown. My HTML for ng-select looks like the following:

```
<ng-select [items]="allEmp$ | async" bindLabel="empName" autofocus bindValue="id"[(ngModel)]="empName"></ng-select>
```

TypeScripts:

```
  results;
  empData;
  empLoading = false;
  allEmp$: Observable<any[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.getAllEmp()
}

getAllEmp(){
    this.empLoading = true;
    this.employeeService.getAll()
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.results = data ;
        console.log(this.results); //1
        this.empLoading = false;
        const mapped = Object.keys(this.results).map(key => ({type: key, value: this.results[key]}));
        console.log(mapped);
        this.allEmp$ = mapped[0].value;
        console.log(this.allEmp$);
      }, error =>{
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

Logs:
1

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "empName": "Emp01"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "empName": "Emp02"
    }
  ]
}
```

2

```
[
  {
    "type": "results",
    "value": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "empName": "Emp01",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "empName": "Emp02"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

3

```
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { id: 1, empName: "Emp01", … }
​
1: Object { id: 2, empName: "Emp02", … }
​
length: 2
​
```

ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the template, allEmp$ expects an Observable.

```
[items]="allEmp$ | async"
```

But, in ts file, you are assigning the array to allEmp$ which is not observable.

```
this.allEmp$ = mapped[0].value; // returns array type
```

To fix the issue,

1. Either remove | async pipe from HTML (or)

   ```
   <ng-select [items]="allEmp$"
   ```
2. Assign observable of the array in ts.

   ```
   this.allEmp$ = from(mapped[0].value); // import { from } from 'rxjs';
   ```

Comment: `console.log(this.allEmp$);` this will log: `Object { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: subscribeToArray(subscriber) }
assign-compensationplan.component.ts:77:16`

Answer (score 0):

1. Async pipe transfer data from an Observable to its value.
   Your code should be:

   [items]="allEmp$ | async"

ts:

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.allEmp$ = this.getAllEmp();
   }

   getAllEmp(){
    this.empLoading = true;
    this.employeeService.getAll().pipe(
      map((data) => {
          this.empLoading = false;
          this.results = data;
          const mapped = Object.keys(this.results).map(key => ({type: key, 
                         value: this.results[key]}));
          return mapped[0]?.value;
         }),
    );
}
```